# Android LinearLayout on top of ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, android-linearlayout

this seems like a very simple issue but I can't seem to figure it out.

I am adding a `LinearLayout` to my active `Activity` when a button is pressed but I want this layout to be on top of the whole activity, that includes the `ActionBar`.  I want the layout to work like a `Dialog` but I think `Dialog` is too heavy for what I am trying to do so I want to use a layout.

I tried applying `Flags` and `Type` when I am setting the layout's `WindowManagerLayoutParams` but nothing helps.

this is what I tried:

```
WindowManagerLayoutParams mainLayoutParams = new WindowManagerLayoutParams ();  
mainLayoutParams.Height = 600;  
mainLayoutParams.Width = 300;  
mainLayoutParams.Gravity = GravityFlags.Center; 
mainLayoutParams.Flags = WindowManagerFlags._______
mainLayoutParams.Type = WindowManagerTypes._______
```

I wrote "______" because I've tried ALL different ones but it makes no difference.

Please give me solution in which I can do this programmatically (not XML) since my layout is created manually.

How can I do this?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When you say "on top", do you mean on the Z axis (higher elevation, "closer" to the user's eyes in theory), or on the Y axis (closer towards the top edge of the screen)?

Comment: I believe Z axis. I want the layout to take up 85% of the screen and rest is covered with an overlay.  So basically a standard `Dialog` or `Alert` look.  I've updated my question to show what I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only is `Dialog` not a particularly "heavy" solution, it is the lightest one that I can think of. Your alternatives would be:

- Rewrite your app to use `Toolbar` in your layouts instead of the action bar, then use a `RelativeLayout` or `FrameLayout` container around the `Toolbar` and main contents. You can then add your floating content to the container as a child, and later children of `RelativeLayout` and `FrameLayout` appear higher on the Z axis. However, this will cause problems on Android 5.0+ with `elevation`, so I would not recommend it.
- You could make your floating thing be a dialog-themed activity (e.g., `Theme.Holo.Dialog`). When you start the activity, it will appear to float over the existing activity.

Comment: I guess my best option is go with a `Dialog`.  Another problem with that is how can I call `AnimationEnd` event on a dialog? I created XML file in my res/anim folder and applying it to dialog this way:  `myDialog = new Dialog (context, Resource.Style.myDialogAnim);`

Comment: @user3866010: The `Dialog` constructor does not take an animation resource, and I have no idea what you are trying to do. I suggest that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question where you explain what you are trying to accomplish related to dialogs and animations, in hopes that somebody can help you.

Comment: The `Dialog` constructor doesn't take an animation resource but it does take style. I created a style in my res/values/styles file that has one item: `windowAnimationStyle` and the value of that item is another style that has two items: `windowEnterAnimation` and `windowExitAnimation`.  This automatically applies animation to the dialog. But I will create a new question. Thanks

Comment: @user3866010: "The Dialog constructor doesn't take an animation resource but it does take style" -- that's not how I interpreted your previous comment, sorry. I have not played with window animations, and so I do not know if you can get your hands on the inflated animation objects to set up an event listener or not. Sorry!